# nginx conf regex for server_name for specific REST route

Tags: regex, nginx

Setting up nginx config for my EC2 server already having a Laravel project deployed. What I require is to allow another domain to access my server, but only a specific REST route. So something like -

`www.otherdomain.com/users/{user_id}/features/{feature_id}`

Where user_id and feature_id could have any value

I have tried a number of regular expressions given on web but I am missing something or maybe something is incorrect. Have always struggled with regex!

This is my current value for server name but it allows access to all routes.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.otherdomain.com/users/[0-9a-z]+/features/[0-9]+/;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: `server_name` cannot contain a *path*. You probably need `location` directive

Comment: Something I was afraid...thanks!

Answer (score -2):

This RegExp matches the literal string up to *users/* looks for any character(s) that isn't a slash, followed by */features/*, followed by any character(s) that isn't a slash:

```
www.otherdomain.com\/users\/[^\\]+\/features\/[^\\]+
```